# Making FQL queries which require two access tokens

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I want to find the common interests between two users of my application and I'm going to use the below query:

```
   $fql= "SELECT interests FROM user WHERE uid=me() AND interests IN 
(SELECT interests FROM user WHERE uid = '100004159483336')"

$mutual_interests = $facebook->api(array('method' => 'fql.query',
'query' => $fql));
```

I am using extended access tokens and the normal way I go about accessing a user's profile information when they're not online is to retrieve their access token from my DB and then `setAccessToken()`.  Since I need access to both the active user's profile and the offline user's profile in order to make this query my normal method will not work.  What is the common protocol for making a facebook query which requires two different access tokens?

- Do I need to make separate queries i.e. make the subquery using one
  access token, store it then use it in the next query?
- If so, how do I store it so that I can provide it as a subset to the
  next query?
- Lastly, is there a way to use an access token in a request (in PHP
  SDK) without switching it into the session variable?  So that the
  scope where it is used is only for that request and then discarded?

Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to make separate queries i.e. make the subquery using one access token, store it then use it in the next query?

If two separate access tokens are required, then you’ll need to queries as well, yes.

> If so, how do I store it so that I can provide it as a subset to the next query?

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/, multi-query

> Lastly, is there a way to use an access token in a request (in PHP SDK) without switching it into the session variable? So that the scope where it is used is only for that request and then discarded?

Yes, the access token can always be given as an extra parameter `access_token` for every Facebook::api call.